# Javascript, Click eventlistener doing the same thing with multiple classes

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to learning JavaScript, and I've tried to read, and look for similar answers, but everything is pointing at jQuery, which I want to avoid using for this problem. I can't quite work out what is jQuery and what still works in JS...

I have set up a function that can grab the innerHTML but I can't seem to assign it to the same classes, else it'll only work on the first instance, and I tried creating multiple classes but essentially they're all the same button with different values...

```
document.querySelector(".b1").addEventListener("click", writeDisp);
document.querySelector(".b2").addEventListener("click", writeDisp);
document.querySelector(".b3").addEventListener("click", writeDisp);
document.querySelector(".b4").addEventListener("click", writeDisp);

function writeDisp() {
  if(dispNum.length < 9){
    if(dispNum === "0") {
      dispNum = this.innerHTML
    } else {
      dispNum = dispNum + this.innerHTML};
      document.querySelector(".display").textContent = dispNum;
    }
  }
}
```

How can I make this more simple. As there are way more .b* classes to add, and I'd rather not have a massive list if possible.

Thanks,

Comment: post a snipped of your html.  If all of the `b` classes are children of an element, you can use jQuery's even propagation with `.on()`

Comment: You can use code snippet to post all html and script.  see -
 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358213/1516712

Comment: what is `dispNum ` here...?

Comment: `document.querySelector(".b1")` returns a single element. You need `document.querySelectorAll`, and then iterate through the returned collection to add the event listeners, or use event delegation, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var class_elem = document.querySelectorAll("button[class^='b']");

function writeDisp(){
  if(dispNum.length < 9){
    if(dispNum === "0"){dispNum = this.innerHTML}else{dispNum = dispNum + this.innerHTML};
    document.querySelector(".display").textContent = dispNum;
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < class_elem.length; i++) {
    class_elem[i].addEventListener('click', writeDisp, false);
}

//Here your code in javascript only.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use jquery, you can use native [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) API like this

```
function writeDisp(){
  if(dispNum.length < 9){
    if(dispNum === "0"){
        dispNum = this.innerHTML
    } else {
        dispNum = dispNum + this.innerHTML
    }
    document.querySelector(".display").textContent = dispNum;
  }
}

// this line will select all html tags that contains a class 
// name starting with 'b'
var doms = document.querySelectorAll("[class^=b]");

doms.forEach(function(dom) {
  dom.addEventListener('click', writeDisp);
})
```

**Note**

`querySelectorAll` will fetch only those DOM instance in which `b*` is defined as first class, so in case of multiple class defintion, it will not fetch those DOMs which don't have the desired classname at first. That means if you have a DOM defintion like `<div class="a box"></div>`, this will be ignored, as here, classname starting with `b` sits after a class.